# Best way to add a second parameter to route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want my route to be something like cars(/:country/):car_id, what is the best way to do that? Only "cars" will list all the cars and "cars /: country" will list all the cars that are made in that country.

Now I have my route like this resources: cars,: path => "cars (/:country)" and I check in cars#index action if params[:country] is nil to determine what will be retrieved from the database .

My solution feels wrong and ugly and I guess the best solution and cleanest would be to make a country model, but do not really know how to organize it all up, tips?
country must have a slug and so do car_id too (using friendly_id for car_id). It feels like I should have a car table with name and slug thats all i have figured out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First I'd say that your current solution is NOT ugly, nor wrong,  at worst it's pedestrian.  But without seeing all the involved models and associations,  I can only give a general answer.

First,  A country model, probably a good idea,  but how do you relate it to the cars model?

You could do this:

```
class Country << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :cars
end
class Car << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```

That would support semantics where by you could select a country, and get all cars belonging to a certain country, i.e.

```
@cars = Country.find('USA').cars
```

OR,  you could do something like:

```
class Car << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :country
end

class Country << ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

That would enable a different semantic:

```
@country = Car.find('Jeep').country
```

The point is to think of the query semantics you'd like to have in your app,  and then define your associations to support the semantics that make sense for your app.  I've posted very simple associations,  you may end up with multiple and more complex associations,  just depends on how you need to query the database and the associated models.

UPDATE

You posted:
I want my route to be something like cars(/:country/):car_id,

That doesn't make sense, if you know the specific car_id,  you don't need any filtering or extra searching.

Sound like you want these URLs:

```
/cars          # all cars
/cars/:country # all cars in country
/car/:id       # a specific car
```

The first and third routes are probably there assuming you've defined the full set of RESTful routes for cars, i.e.

config/routes.rb

```
resources :cars
```

You just need to add to routes.rb:

```
GET '/cars/:country' => 'cars#index'
```

Then in app/controllers/cars_controller.rb:

```
def index
  if params[:country]
    @cars = Car.where("country_id = ?", params[:country])
  else
    @cars = Car.all
  end
end
```

This assumes you have a relationship set up whereby each car record has a country_id attribute.  That can come about in several ways, for example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country
end
```

That says my car table has a country_id attribute,  and I can do something like:

@car = Car.find(1001)

"The car is in #{@car.country.name}"

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I want my routes to be cars/:country/:car. I could easy just do so cars belongs to a country i.e countries/:country/:car but thats not what i want to accomplish.
The importent thing for my app is that  just the URL car shows all cars (cars#index), URL cars/:category shows all cars from a specific country (mabybe cars#by_country?) and ofcourse cars/:country/:car (cars#show).
Create a country model would be the best but I dont know what the best solution for the associations and routes?

Comment: /cars/:country and /car/:id may also work.The thing is that /cars/:country/:id  feels more logic.
If the user navigates to /cars/ and chooses a car then /car/:id feels RESTful.
But if the user navigates to /cars/:country and chooses a car then  /cars/:country/:id feels RESTful. What's the best solution? And if I go with /cars/:country how would I accomplish that?

Comment: After some research I found that use a singular name for only one action like car/:id is not RESTful. More ideas are welcome.

Comment: Not so,  if you ask rails to generate the full set of seven RESTFul routes, i.e.  in routes.rb:  resources :cars,  you'll get the route GET '/car/:id' => 'cars#show'

Comment: Not in rails 3. If I do resources :cars then all my routes will be cars/*

Comment: You're right, I never noticed until now.  But '/car/:id'  is still perfectly RESTFul,  just not the Rails convention.  All you really need to do to be RESTFul is to make sure GET's just read data, POSTs create data,  etc.   I think if you went with /car/:id to show an individual car,  and /cars/:country to call the index action filtered on country,  that's prefectly acceptable.  I have 85 routes in one app,  only 45 or so are conventional Rails Resource based routes, the rest are whatever I needed to get the job done.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. But I just realised that in my app a car can have the same name like another car in a different country and when i use friendly id to make car name to id conflicts can occur. So the best would probably if I go with my route solution and make a assosiation between cars and country.